# Ubuntu Server 14.03 lts not showing in Windows 10 Pro Networking

Tags: windows-10

I'm using Ubuntu server as my NAS and is connecting and mapping drives  successfully through, XP Vista, Win 7 Win 8.1.

Lately I've installed Windows 10 Pro on to another PC which after the installation completed I can also map drives successfully. Then windows 10 downloaded the latest update/upgrade to Windows 10, Version 1511, build 10586 and suddenly the Ubuntu server will not appear in the windows network window and neither can I map any drives.

I've tried installing earlier and later versions of the network device driver but to no avail.

I'm running Zone-Alarm Pro on all my machines and cannot blame the Zone-Alarm software because I can access the Ubuntu server and map drives on other machines successfully not running Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I came across this same situation the other day I found if I open network in Windows explorer then typed in the address or the nameserver it was able to locate it. I then mapped the ubuntu drives. This however does not solve the problem of the server not showing in the network. Everything works fine otherwise.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and yes, I've since discovered the same and was rather surprised but my mapped drives works fine. Though it may seem a small issue, it is still a little disconcerting not to see the network link.

Comment: I agree and am curious to find out where the settings are in windows 10 to display it correctly. I've read on various sites that windows will not "see" ubuntu and I understand that due to different file systems. However, it was visible before I installed the latest build. Therefore I'm at a loss as well.

Comment: This problem seems to have sorted itself out with with windows updates.